# Creating modeless dialog in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

Is there a way to create a modeless dialog in ADF? I would like to display some readonly information in a popup but I don't want to block the user from using the main browser content until the popup is closed. Is there anyway I can achieve this in ADF? I am also open to arguments regarding whether this is a good design...is there anything else in ADF that I can use to allow users to view this read only information while still able to use the main browser content. They would ideally like to see both (the browser and this read only info) at the same time, but if it can be display with a keystroke then that's acceptable too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default way of showing validation errors in ADF is based on Modeless Dialogs.
Therefore, if you show a JSFMessage, this shows up as a modeless popup/dialog.

Moreover, if you use ADF BC components and using ADF with Bindings (default way of ADF), you can simply:

```
 throw new JboException("your message here")
```

and this will get you the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

`af:dialog` has the `modal` property, set it to false to have it modeless.
Also you can just put your layout in popup without dialog, or use `af:panelWindow` as dialog replacement.